# Simulating Azure Scheduler with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, scheduler, basic-authentication, azure-scheduler

How can I locally reproduce the https GET call that my Azure Scheduler job would execute that uses Basic Authentication with a username/password?

I know I can just type in the URL in the browser to hit the action in my MVC controller, but how does Azure Scheduler send the username/password?

Answer (score 2):

If Azure Scheduler uses [`Basic Authentication`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) then it will send the username and password as Base64 encoded `Authorization` header.

> 1. The username and password are combined into a string separated by a colon, e.g.: username:password
> 2. The resulting string is encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line.
> 3. The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.

So for example if your username=john and password=secret, the Authorization header would look like this:

```
Authorization: Basic am9objpzZWNyZXQ=
```

So you should make the following HTTP request:

```
GET /yourcontroller/youraction HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic am9objpzZWNyZXQ=
Connection: close
```